# Is there a way to start and stop logging multiple lines of statements and time to execute?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging

Let's say I have a unit test like this:

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setColor("blue");
    car.setSize("big");
}
```

I want to see how much time it takes to execute the statement, is there a "Log with timer" feature like below to record every statement it has executed (and its time taken)?

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){
    logWithTimer.start();
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setColor("blue");
    car.setSize("big");
    logWithTimer.finish();
}
```

So when I run the unit test above, the output will be like this:

```
15:23:456 Car car = new Car();
15:23:470 car.setColor("blue");
15:23:500 car.setSize("big");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it.

But it's probably not going to work with what you had in mind `logWithTimer.start();` and `logWithTimer.finish();`

You need to consider Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).

- Try aspectj - testSomething statements executions can be picked up with it. [Check out the cheat list](https://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/) for examples

> ```
> @Pointcut("withincode(* aspects.trace.demo.*.*(..))")
> public void traceMethodsInDemoPackage() {}
> ```
>
> **withincode** - all the statements inside the methods in the demo
>   package.

Note - Spring AOP does not support **withincode** , doesn't fully
   implement AspectJ so you wouldn't actually be using the @Pointcut annotation, but the pointcut of an .aj file

In your case you can combine package pointcuts or just change that one to have a wildcard, so that the classes end with *Test .

Or even create an annotation, so that on top of the class being in a Test file, it would also have to contain either your custom annotation, or just the @Test annotation already there.

- Within the advice , you can print out the current system time or time elapsed

> ```
> long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
> // ... do something ...
> long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
> ```

- To get the current line **number**, you can use [this little helper](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.StaticPart.html)
  . Can be accessed within advice using the special form thisJoinPointStaticPart.

> ```
> String sourceName = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getWithinType().getCanonicalName();
> String line =""+thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getLine();
> ```
>
> [source with output examples](https://mathewjhall.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/tracing-java-method-execution-with-aspectj/)

- At this point you want the source code line.
  You will need to read the .java file separately based on the **sourceName** and then go to the line number. Don't think you'll know the name at runtime, so you'll to build something else just to read the output file your produce here.

Comment: thanks buddy, now reading it, by the way - you should fix your link https://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Have you pulled it off?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this?

I think it is theoretically possible to implement only as a source instrumentation.

Say, a maven plugin which wraps *every* line into a logging statement.
(or a java agent with bytecode instrumentation but there is no guarantee to 100% match to the source code).

Though, it looks weird (and affects the timings).

I guess you have to optimize something.
Would VisualVM CPU profiling work for you?

[Understanding CPU time in visualvm profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049172/understanding-cpu-time-in-visualvm-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JUnit 5 which have a Timing Extension, it may be what you need:  http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks-timing-extension

You can use the annotation to cause JUnit to display timing data about the test methods in that class.

Comment: But not about the statements.

Comment: I can't think of anything that can do that without using an actual profiler.  What OP is asking for is a profiler like behavior in unit tests which is not something you can just throw a switch and make it work.  They should check either visualVm or YourKit or other profilers.

Comment: I thought of a way, suggested some general guidelines. If he bothers playing out with that he can achieve it. Harder to get the actual line names, but doable.